# feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Tags: php, python, html

im trying to make a hash identifier, im not too good with php but i can just about make simple things, i keep getting these 2 errors repeated in my error_log

```
feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in *** on line 48
fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in *** on line 50
```

and heres my script

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Online Hash Identifier</title>
<style type='text/css'>
 body{
 background:#000;
 color: #7FFF00;
 font-family:'Lucida Console',sans-serif !important;
 font-size: 12px;
 }
fieldset {
border: 0;
}
 </style>
<body>  


<form method="post" action="hash.php" name="checkcodes" id="checkcodes">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Enter Hash to identify : </label><input type="text" name="code" id="code" />
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Submit" required />
    </fieldset>



<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['code']))
{
    $param1 = $_POST['code'];
    $param1 = str_replace(' ', '',$param1);
    $filter = '!^[\w @.-]*$!';
    $b64pram = base64_encode($param1); 



    $command = "python Hash_ID_v1.1.py";
    $command .= " $b64pram  2>&1";

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
    echo " <button ONCLICK='history.go(-1)'>Back</button><br />";

    $pid = popen( $command,"r");

    echo "<body><pre>";
    while( !feof( $pid ) )
        {
         echo fread($pid, 256);
         flush();
         ob_flush();
         echo "<script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";
         usleep(100000);
        }
    pclose($pid);

    echo "</pre><script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";

}
?>
```

anyone got any ideas why its not working ?

Comment: It seems to me that `popen` is returning null

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: @abarnert Because of `$command = "python Hash_ID_v1.1.py";` or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @abarnert If you feel I made a mistake, then by all means delete the tag if you think it's not Python-related.